# python cross platform testing: mocking os.name

Tags: python, testing, mocking, nose

### what is the correct way to mock `os.name`?

I am trying to unittest some cross-platform code that uses `os.name` to build platform-appropriate strings. I am running on a Windows machine but want to test code that can run on either posix or windows.

I've tried:

#### production_code.py

```
from os import name as os_name

def platform_string():
    if 'posix' == os_name:
      return 'posix-y path'
    elif 'nt' == os_name:
      return 'windows-y path'
    else:
      return 'unrecognized OS'
```

#### test_code.py

```
import production as production 
from nose.tools import patch, assert_true

class TestProduction(object):
    def test_platform_string_posix(self):
    """
    """
    with patch.object(os, 'name') as mock_osname:
        mock_osname = 'posix'
        result = production.platform_string()
    assert_true('posix-y path' == result)
```

this fails because `os` is not in the global scope for the `test_code.py`. If 'os' is `import`ed in `test_code.py` then we will always get `os.name=='nt'`.

I've also tried:

```
def test_platform_string_posix(self):
    """
    """
    with patch('os.name', MagicMock(return_value="posix")):
        result = production.platform_string()
    assert_true('posix-y path' == result)
```

in the test, but this seems not to work because `os.name` is an attribute not a method with a return value.

EDIT:
clarifications in response to comments

1. The [mock docs (1st paragraph)](http://mock.readthedocs.org/en/latest/patch.html) make it seem like directly monkey patching `os.name` could get messy if e.g. an assertion gets raised
2. We really are only changing a path based on `os.name`. Whilst tests will be run on windows and posix machines I wanted something that gave full coverage without needing to resource a machine every time a small edit is made.

Comment: Why not just assign the value you want: `os.name = 'posix'`?

Comment: You probably also have code that can't be tested simply by mocking `os.name`. You'd be better off setting up a virtual machine running an actual POSIX environment to run those tests.

Comment: in test:
`with patch('production.os_name', 'posix'):`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) you should patch `os_name` in `production_code`. By

```
from os import name as os_name
```

you are creating a `os.name`'s reference in `production_code` module called `os_name`: after that (loaded at import time) change `os.name` have no effect `os_name` reference.

```
class TestProduction(object):
    @patch("production_code.os_name","posix")
    def test_platform_string_posix(self):
        assert_equal('posix-y path', production.platform_string())
```